# Combine Two Variable Filters Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two filters in my code here, students filters everyone in that particular class and students_wr is another filter that quieres my table K8Recess which logs all the students in the school who got recess for that day. What I want to do is combine these filters.

So show everyone in my class who got recess for the day . How do i do that ? Here is my Code

```
def K8_Recess_Report(request, classid):
    if request.method == "GET":
       date = datetime.date.today()
       class_name = TeacherClass.objects.get(id=classid)
       getstudents = Student.objects.filter(class_name=classid)
       students = getstudents.all().order_by('student_name')
       students_wr = K8Recess.objects.filter(created_at__date = date )
       my_class_id = request.session['my_class_id']
       context = ({'students': students, 'class_name': class_name, 'my_class_id': my_class_id, 'date': date,})
    return render(request, 'points/k8_recess_report.html', context)
```

```
class K8Points(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today()) 
    class_name = models.ForeignKey(TeacherClass, on_delete = models.PROTECT, default = "",)
    student_name = models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete = models.CASCADE, default ="" ,) 
    week_of = models.IntegerField(default=weeknumber)
    day = models.CharField(max_length= 10, default = dayofweek)
    TIME_FRAME_CHOICES = [
        (None, 'PLEASE SELECT TIME FRAME'),  # THIS IS OPTIONAL
        (1, '(1.) 8:45AM - 9:00AM'),
        (2, '(2.) 9:00AM - 9:30AM'),
        (3, '(3.) 9:30AM - 10:00AM'),
        (4, '(4.) REC. I 10:00AM -10:10AM'),
        (5, '(5.) 10:10AM-10:40AM'),
        (6, '(6.) 10:40AM-11:10AM'),
        (7, '(7.) 11:10AM-11:40AM'),
        (8, '(8.) LUNCH 11:40AM-12:00PM'),
        (9, '(9.) REC. II 12:00PM-12:20PM'),
        (10, '(10.) 12:20PM-12:50PM'),
        (11,'(11.) 12:50PM-1:20PM'),
        (12,'(12.) 1:20PM-1:50PM'),
        (13,'(13.) 1:50PM-2:20PM'),
        (14,'(14.) REC. III 2:20PM-2:30PM'),
    ]
    time_frame = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=TIME_FRAME_CHOICES,)
    behavior = models.IntegerField(default="", validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(5),
            MinValueValidator(1)
        ])
    academic = models.IntegerField(default="", validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(5),
            MinValueValidator(0)
        ] )

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "K8-Points"


    def __str__(self):
        return self.student_name  

class K8Recess(models.Model):
    student_ps = models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete = models.CASCADE, default ="" ,) 
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    morning_recess = models.BooleanField(blank= True, null = True)
    lunch_recess = models.BooleanField(blank= True, null = True)
    afternoon_recess = models.BooleanField(blank= True, null = True)
```

[image]

Comment: I guess you have a `student` field on K8Recess model. If this is so, you can do this: `students_recess_today = K8Recess.objects.filter(student__class_name=classid, created_at__date=date)`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I will post my models hold on so you see the setup.

Comment: Well, so you have `student_ps` (instead of `student` as I suggested) field that is a `ForeignKey` of `Student` class. So you can do `K8Recess.objects.filter(student_ps__class_name=classid, created_at__date=date)`. Check if it works, please.

Comment: Awesome that worked however is there anyway to show that on one line as apposed to individual lines ?

Comment: Happy to hear that it worked! I don't understand your last question though, sorry...

Comment: Look at screen shot. Its doing what its suppose to, showing the three records, but is it possible to show it just on one line ?

Comment: Sure, but that is related with context/templating, not filtering, so it is off-topic. I will chat you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207287/discussion-between-oz19-and-ray-zuchowski).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this by:

```
K8Recess.objects.filter(student_ps__class_name=classid, created_at__date=date)
```